# Confusion how to handle array return

Tags: php, arrays

```
function get_galleryxml_row($table_data)
{
   $xml_output = array();

   if ($table_data)
   {
        foreach($table_data as $key => $row)
        {
             $xml_output[] .=   $this->exporter->get_property_gallery_data($key['id']);

        }

        return implode(" ",    $xml_output);
   }
}
```

get_property_gallery_data Returns area of images and urls which does contain data and I have checked but some reason i am getting the follow error.

Array to string conversion  and it states this line as the error

```
$xml_output[] .=   $this->exporter->get_property_gallery_data($key['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of `.` -

```
$xml_output[] =   $this->exporter->get_property_gallery_data($row['id']); // It should be only $key or $row['id']
```

It will store the value with new index. `.` is used to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 $xml_output[] .=   $this->exporter->get_property_gallery_data($key['id']);


to 

 $xml_output[] =   $this->exporter->get_property_gallery_data($row['id']);
```

Comment: no that is not correct it then produces  Illegal string offset 'id' as that key exists in the record data for sure and i have vardump to check

Comment: Post your array with question